# Ковариационная матрица в Python (сравнение с R)

Tags: python, r

Как удобнее было бы представить `t=vcov(m)[1,1]` в Python?

P.S. `vcov(m)` возвращает ковариационную матрицу объекта `m`. `[1,1]` - это индексы, по которым можно однозначно возвратить элемент данной матрицы.

```
t=vcov(m)[1,1]+vcov(m)[2,2]*(d/100)^2+vcov(m)[3,3]*b^2+vcov(m)[4,4]*a^2+vcov(m)[5,5]*(log(c))^2+
2*vcov(m)[1,2]*d/100+2*vcov(m)[1,3]*b+2*vcov(m)[1,4]*a+2*vcov(m)[1,5]*log(c)+
2*vcov(m)[2,3]*d/100*b+2*vcov(m)[2,4]*d/100*a+2*vcov(m)[2,5]*d/100*log(c)+
2*vcov(m)[3,4]*b*a+2*vcov(m)[3,5]*log(c)*b+
2*vcov(m)[4,5]*a*log(c)+deviance(m)/(nrow(work_file)-5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Python для работы с матрицами существует специальный модуль NumPy.
Есть в нём и функция для создания ковариационной матрицы - numpy.cov

Подробнее можно почитать, например, здесь:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html